# Copying files from old Ubuntu HDD to a new Ubuntu HDD

Tags: hard-drive, transfer

BACKGROUND: I installed Ubuntu (latest version at the time) several months ago to an old PC. It worked great, but recently the hard drive has had some errors when booting. Sometimes it boots fine, other times I get all sorts of disk errors. I ran the "Disks" program from Ubuntu, and it did not pass.

So I bought a brand new hard drive yesterday, removed the old drive from the PC, installed the new hard drive in the PC, and installed Ubuntu to the new hard drive using a Ubuntu Live on a USB stick. Everything's fine, Ubuntu is running smoothly, etc.

QUESTION: Is there a way I can run Ubuntu from the new hard drive but also have the old hard drive connected to the PC so that I can copy files from the old hard drive to the new hard drive?

It is probably only 30 or 40 files. I realize I could plug the old drive back in, boot from it, save files to a USB, etc., but I am wondering if there is a way to do it directly from the old hard drive to the new hard drive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a compatible **spare connector in your computer**, you can temporarily add it again to your current system. Then, on a subsequent boot, Ubuntu will (should, if it is not broken too much) recognize the drive. It should appear in the left pane of file manager, and you can then mount it by clicking on it in the left panel.

It could work by connecting the drive on a connector of a computer over the network, etc...

An option that costs some money is to obtain a **hard drive docking station** in which you plug the hard drive, then connect through USB. Such docking stations are priced between $25-35.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I followed your first suggestion and connected the old HDD to a connector labeled "SATA_6G 1" on the motherboard. I rebooted and was able to see the old HDD in Ubuntu's "Files" program. I copied files to the new HDD by simply dragging/dropping as  needed. Thanks so much for the helpful response!